# code first migration not working when deploying to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I am building an MVC 5 website with code first migration approach. Also, mention that I'm using Visual Studio Online linking to my Azure Web site. So, when I use Team Explorer in VS 2013 to do a check in, it automatically is deployed to Azure web sites.

Locally all works OK. However, when deploying it to Azure (check in) the following points are NOT performed:

1. If a new table is created using the code first approach, it is not created when deploying to Azure
2. The seed method (in the configuration.cs file) is not executed.

Due to the above, I have to manually either create the new tables or adding the test data. Google it for a solution I have read that this is a problem in the .Net framework due to the kind of index (nonclustered) to is set by default.

So, I have trying to use different alternatives. As for example:

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    ContextKey = "MySolution.Models.ApplicationDbContext";

    SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new AzureSqlGenerator());
}
```

Where I created the **AzureSqlGenerator** class:

```
public class AzureSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
    {
        protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)
        {
            if ((createTableOperation.PrimaryKey != null)
                && !createTableOperation.PrimaryKey.IsClustered)
            {
                createTableOperation.PrimaryKey.IsClustered = true;
            }

            base.Generate(createTableOperation);
        }
    }
```

But, that doesn't work.

Long story short, I have the following two questions:

1. Is it possible to migrate the tables and its data when deploying to Azure?
2. If so, what would be the correct steps to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your SQL user have the permission to create tables

Comment: not sure if I understand the question. There is no users at this point. The users is the kind of data I want to add to the tables when deploying to Azure.

Comment: I wanted to check out the permission for the SQL server user that you have in the connection string

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate tables. To migrate data, you should use Seed method of entity framework.

```
public class SchoolDBInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SchoolDBContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(SchoolDBContext context)
        {
            IList<Standard> defaultStandards = new List<Standard>();

            defaultStandards.Add(new Standard() { StandardName = "Standard 1", Description = "First Standard" });
            defaultStandards.Add(new Standard() { StandardName = "Standard 2", Description = "Second Standard" });
            defaultStandards.Add(new Standard() { StandardName = "Standard 3", Description = "Third Standard" });

            foreach (Standard std in defaultStandards)
                context.Standards.Add(std);

            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx

In my opinion the best you can do, use Sql Server Data Tools. It will help you with tables and also data, because it uses a declarative mode. You 'declare' how should be your database, and it handles de updates.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPll3dMxTXU